# Change MenuItem Background color

Tags: wpf, menuitem

Please see this `MenuItem` `style`:

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Background" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

My `MenuItem` `Background` color is `Gray` as defined but when the mouse is over this not changed into `Red` but something else.

Comment: <Style TargetType="MenuItem">

Comment: It's just your first mistake. If it would be answer, I would not post comment.

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't understand.

Comment: Your code works. You can also remove "MenuItem." from setters.